# Switching away from an MVVMCross app cancels the IMvxNavigationService task

Tags: mvvmcross

I have an MVVMCross 8.0.1 android app, using XamarinForms, with 2 view models:

- ViewModel1
- ViewModel2

ViewModel1 will perform a navigation to ViewModel2 and await the result. However if the user switches to another app while in ViewModel2, a Task Canceled Exception will be thrown in ViewModel1 so it will never receive the result from ViewModel2.

This is the relevant code from ViewModel1:

```
private async Task ShowView()
{
    try
    {
        var output = await navSvc.Navigate<ViewModel2, string, string>(string.Empty);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

And this is the relevant code from ViewModel2:

```
private async Task CloseView()
{
    await this.navSvc.Close(this, string.Empty);
}
```

If the user switches away from the app while in ViewModel2, these lifecycle methods will be called:

- *ViewDisappearing*
- *ViewDisappeared*
- *ViewDestroy*

After ViewModel2.ViewDestroy is called, the Task Canceled Exception will be thrown in ViewModel1.

Is this a known issue? If not how can I keep ViewModel2 present so that ViewModel1 will get the result from ViewModel2?

Comment: It shouldn't work like that. Are you doing something on `ViewDisappearing`, `ViewDisappeared` or `ViewDestroy` ? When/Where are you calling `CloseView`? Just in case the code that is causing the TaskCancelledException is here https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/MvvmCross/ViewModels/MvxViewModel.cs#L100

Comment: There is nothing being done on ViewDisappearing, ViewDisappeared, or ViewDestroy. Remember, these are not called until the user switches away from the app. At that point These methods are called in that order. After ViewDestroy is called, the ViewModel1.ShowViewModel() method will receive a Task Canceled Exception. And I am not calling CloseView.

Comment: HI again, I've checked and found an issue about this https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/3158 they talk about this and some workarounds. Also there is a pending PR https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/pull/3292 but hasn't been approved. IDK how far are you in your application, but I wouldn't use MvvmCross on Xamarin.Forms, it doesn't give you that much value added in the current version of XF